# java.net.bindexception address already on running more than one tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to run more than one tomcat instance on my server. I can successfully run tomcat 7 on port 8080. I am trying to run another tomcat on port 8181 the server is refusing to start with the following error

```
java.net.bindexception address already in use
```

This is my port configuration

```
<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Please what could be wrong. Kindly assist.

Comment: A tomcat instance uses more than one port. Make sure you have changed all.

Comment: problem is some other service instance running on the same port . change the port to any other

Comment: Just interesting, why do you need to start two Tomcat servers on one server instance, if you can put all applications in one and make mapping by application manager?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat uses three ports while it's running.

By default it's `8080` for HTTP, `8005` for SHUTDOWN and `8009` for AJP.

You've changed `8080` to `8181`, so change below two configurations as well.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: please I should change it to what? may be 8001

Comment: what about the redirectPort. It should be left as it is

Comment: Yes, you can change it to `8006` and `8010`, if it's not used elsewhere. You  need not to change redirect port.

Comment: I have changed all three and still getting the issues of not starting